# Change message in auth feathers js

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm trying to change the message of sendResetPwd on feather auth management because he has security issues, I think

I have this result

```
BadRequest: User not found.
    at new BadRequest (node_modules/@feathersjs/errors/lib/index.js:86:17)
    at getUserData (/node_modules/feathers-authentication-management/lib/helpers.js:93:11)
    at node_modules/feathers-authentication-management/lib/sendResetPwd.js:32:14
```

Is there a way to change message "User not found"

Same for

```
BadRequest: User is not verified.
```

Thanks in advance
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack solution
In feathers app-hoks set this

```
error: {
    all: [
      preventErrorMessages,
    ]
}
```

and check for 'sendResetPwd' in context and set new message error fired up